# Google Prediction API with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following this example, and at the bottom it has some code
https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/developer-guide

I'm using Flask instead of webapp2 and my code looks like this:

```
# [START app]
import logging
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from flask import Flask
import httplib2, webapp2
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

http = AppAssertionCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction').authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build('prediction', 'v1.6', http=http)


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World1!'

@app.route('/add')
def something():
    class MakePrediction():
      def get(self):
        result = service.hostedmodels().predict(project=PROJECT-NAME, hostedModelName=PROJECT-ID, body={'input' {'csvInstance': ['hello']}}).execute()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Result: ' + repr(result))


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    # Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
# [END app]
```

I keep getting the error:

```
  File "/Users/morganallen/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/morganallen/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/morganallen/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/morganallen/Desktop/project/flask_app_engine/main.py", line 24
    result = service.hostedmodels().predict(project='linear-yen-140912', hostedModelName='language-identifier', body={'input' {'csvInstance': ['hello']}}).execute()
                                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are missing a colon on line 24, where the little carrot is pointing to in the stack trace:**

```
  File "/Users/morganallen/Desktop/project/flask_app_engine/main.py", line 24
result = service.hostedmodels().predict(project='linear-yen-140912', hostedModelName='language-identifier', body={'input' {'csvInstance': ['hello']}}).execute()
                                                                                                                          ^
```

**So the solution here is change this:**

```
body={'input' {'csvInstance': ['hello']}}).execute()
              ^
```

**To this:**

```
body={'input' : {'csvInstance': ['hello']}}).execute()
              ^
```

That should solve the syntax error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Whenever you get an error, don't ignore all the lines that the compiler spits out. It will often tell you the exact line of a problem, especially in the case of a simple syntax error like this one.